# Representing second derivatives with a double overdot

Tags: syntax, formatting

I would like to express a second derivative with two dots above the variable. You can do this with a first derivative by saying:

```
f[x_] := OverDot[x];
Print[HoldForm[f[x]], " == ", f[x]]
```

Is there a possible syntax to do this with the second derivative?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
g[x_] := Overscript[x, ".."]
Print[HoldForm[g[x]], " == ", g[x]]
```

You could use AdjustmentBox to tweak the two dots, but maybe this is not necessary.

Comment: Awesome, this works just how I want it to. -- Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You may also find utility in this:

```
Format[f''[x_]] := Overscript[x, ".."]

f''[j]
```

See the documentation for [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Format.html) for more information.